# Convert a datetime column into a specific date format. (T-SQL)

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a `datetime` column (`SellDate`) that I want to output in the following format:

```
mm/dd/yyyy
```

such as `06/01/1998`

How would I do this?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: See [Books Online: CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) which has a complete list of all supported formats for `CONVERT`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Convert it to a string with the appropriate [conversion style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx);

```
convert(varchar(10), thedatecol, 101)
```

Answer (score 0):

to get date in DD/MM/YYYY
**convert(varchar(10), TransactionDateTime, 103)**
OutPut: **01-07-2018**